# Updating the correct UITableViewCell in the background after fetching data from a server

Tags: ios

My UITableViewCells have a UIButton as their accessoryView. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I fetch data from a server in the background using a block. When the block is called, I set the `selected` property of the button in the cell depending on the data that was retrieved.

When the user scrolls quickly up and down the TableView, some button states are sometimes set incorrectly. I believe this is because the wrong UITableViewCell is being used inside the block (that it is a reused cell instead of the actual cell, which is now probably offscreen).

How do I ensure that the cell inside my block is the cell I want?

Here's a simplified version of my code that contains the important parts:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //FoundUserCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell
    FoundUserCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[self cellIdentifierTableView:tableView]];    

    //set the textLabel (this works already)
    cell.textLabel = @"something";

    //fetch info from the DB that I need to state the state of the button
    //theButton is a property of FoundUserCell
    //theButton is always set to a FoundUserCell's accessoryView
    [self fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int buttonState) {

        //I think that, at this point, cell is sometimes no longer the cell I want            

        if(buttonState == 0)
            cell.theButton.selected = NO;
        else
            cell.theButton.selected = YES;

        //WHAT CAN I DO INSIDE THIS BLOCK TO MAKE SURE THAT THE CELL I'M SETTING IS THE CELL I WANT?
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Basically, I don't want set the state of the button inside the block if the cell is not the correct cell.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the cell will be reused(changed), so you must get the right cell in the block,

```
[self fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int buttonState) {
        UITableViewCell *rightCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // code with rightCell
}];
```